# Log Euler simulation scheme for Cox–Ingersoll–Ross model

Tags: simulation, stochastic-processes, monte-carlo, stochastic-approximation

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox%E2%80%93Ingersoll%E2%80%93Ross_model

In this article the Cox–Ingersoll–Ross is given. I want to design a simulation scheme for this process. A continuous SDE can be discretized is also given in the article. However I want to use another approach and design a *Log Euler Simulation* for the CIR process.

So for a set of given parameter **how do I construct a Log Euler simulation scheme for the CIR  model?**